# Сортировка строк/слов по числу входящему в строку/слово

Tags: python, сортировка

Существует набор слов с цифрами в них

```
a = ("word5 wo3rd wor2d w4ord 1word")
```

Нужна сортировка по возрастанию чисел в слове, числа оставить на месте. То есть примерно:

```
a = ("1word wor2d wo3rd w4ord word5")
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Разбиваете строку на слова, из слов вычленяете цифры ассоциируя их с словами, сортируете по числам, выводите слова. Пожалуйста.

Comment: а такой набор слов может быть ?  `a = "word5 wo33rd wor22d word 1word w1o2rd"`

Comment: да, с любым числом и по возрастанию

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re

a = "word5 wo3rd wor2d w4ord 1word"
res = ' '.join(sorted(a.split(), key=lambda x: int(re.sub(r'.*?(\d+).*', r'\1', x+'_99999'))))
print(res)
```

результат:

```
1word wor2d wo3rd w4ord word5
```

---

```
In [33]: a = "word5 wo33rd wor22d word 1word w1o2rd"

In [34]: print(' '.join(sorted(a.split(), key=lambda x: int(re.sub(r'.*?(\d+).*', r'\1', x+'_99999')))))
1word w1o2rd word5 wor22d wo33rd word
```

---

пошагово:

```
In [37]: a = "word5 wo33rd wor22d word 1word w1o2rd"

In [38]: [re.sub(r'.*?(\d+).*', r'\1',x+'_99999') for x in a.split()]
Out[38]: ['5', '33', '22', '99999', '1', '1']

In [39]: sorted([re.sub(r'.*?(\d+).*', r'\1',x+'_99999') for x in a.split()], key=int)
Out[39]: ['1', '1', '5', '22', '33', '99999']
```

Comment: А как насчет такого `, key=lambda x: int(re.sub('\D', '', x))`?

Comment: a если такая строка `a = "word5 wo33rd wor22d word 1word w1o2rd"`

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, я тоже так вначале хотел, но потом подумал, что лучше сортировать только по первому попавшемуся числу в строке

Comment: @S.Nick, исправил ответ, так, чтобы с вашей строкой тоже правильно работало ;)

Answer (score 4):

Как-то так:

```
import re

a = "word5 wo3rd wor2d w4ord 1word"
b=list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', a)))
res=[a[0] for a in sorted(zip(a.split(), b),key=lambda x: x[1])]
print(' '.join(res))
```

Получим:

```
1word wor2d wo3rd w4ord word5
```

Answer (score 2):

После разбития на слова и получения чисел из них примените функции `index_humansorted()` и `order_by_index()` из модуля [natsort](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html):

```
import natsort                                         # pip install natsort

a = "word5 wo3rd wor2d w4ord 1word w42ord"
words = a.split()

nums = ["".join(d for d in word if d.isdigit())
                  for word in words]                   # список чисел из списка слов
index = natsort.index_humansorted(nums)                # индекс для сортировки
sorted_words = natsort.order_by_index(words, index)    # сортировка для индекса

print(sorted_words)                                    # Тест
```

Вывод:

> ```
> ['1word', 'wor2d', 'wo3rd', 'w4ord', 'word5', 'w42ord']
> ```

(Имя *natsort* значит *натуральная сортировка* - не лексикографическая  `"1" < "22" < "3"`, а человечская: `"1" < "3" < "22"`.)